# Converted PDF from html is not read by screen reader

Tags: pdf-generation, acrobat, screen-readers, abcpdf

I am working on a .Net application which converts html to pdf using Winnovative htmltopdf and the produced PDF should be read by Screen readers ( currently we are testing using JAWS screen reader). but the produced PDF is not readable by screen reader with ADA compliance. meaning if there is heading 1  with text ' this is heading 1 ' it should be reading as heading 1 this is heading 1 but it is reading just like a plain text (just reading as this is heading 1). the tag properties of PDF says No. so I thought it was the reason.
              But, I have also tried with ABCPdf. now the PDF tag properties says Yes and it still reading as plain text. can someone who has already done similar kind of thing (to produce a PDF from html using some .Net library and is readable by screen readers) share the right way which I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: You might add the information about what PDF version you are generating. I think this behaviour might depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was using Itext 3 version which doesn't support accessibility features. Itext 5 was supporting and now the produced pdf from html has a property of tagged ,Yes' and readable by screen readers.